# Updating \if@firstcolumn mid-paragraph

Tags: two-column, marginpar, marginnote

I want to adjust the `\marginnote` command (from the `marginnote` package) to work with `twocolumn` documents  (like `\marginpar` can, but with the ability to use it e.g. inside a `minipage`). For this, I need to know in which column the note is.

`\marginpar` uses `\if@firstcolumn` for this (in `\@addmarginpar`). This switch, however, is only updated after each paragraph, leading to a wrong value in paragraphs that break over column breaks. As can be seen in the MWE below, `\marginpar` gets around this issue somehow.

Is it possible to update `\if@firstcolumn` mid-paragraph? If it is not, how can I ensure that `\marginnote` sets the note in the correct margin?

---

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\setlength\columnsep{2cm}

\usepackage{marginnote}

\makeatletter

\long\def\cc#1#2{%
    \begingroup
    \count@=0%
    \loop\ifnum\count@<#1\advance\count@ 1\relax#2\repeat
    \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\cc{22}{%
    \cc{22}{\if@firstcolumn first \else second \fi}%
    \rule{1em}{1em} \marginpar{\the\count@}%
    \cc{22}{\if@firstcolumn first \else second \fi}%
    \par
}

\end{document}
```

[image: The output of the code above.]

Comment: you can't usefully change it mid paragraph as a paragraph is fully set (including the expansion of all macros and `\if...` tests) while the paragraph is being set in a single line before being broken in to lines and those lines assigned to columns. You could (for example) use `\pdfsavepos` to record a position and look in the next run at the x coordinate of that position

Comment: You are right about the image. It seems I forgot to update the screenshot from an earlier version. I used `\marginpar` in the example to show that it is not affected by the fact that `\if@firstcolumn` is incorrect where `\marginpar` is called (I assume it is somehow typeset after the paragraph is finished.)

Comment: I need to put some paragraphs into a `minipage` in order to avoid column breaks between them. This prevents me from using `\marginpar`.

Comment: Doesn't `marginnote` need two runs anyway?

Comment: `\marginpar` sets both left and right version and forces an internal page break that (usually) allows latex to guess which column it will land on (which is why it can't be in a minpage)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, `\pdfsavepos` indeed seems to be the way to got! Do you want to make your comment an answer?

Comment: `marginnote` since 1.4 does work with `twocolumn` documents and places the notes of the left column to the left margin and of the right column to the right margin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't usefully change `\if@firstcolumn` mid paragraph as a paragraph is fully set (including the expansion of all macros and `\if...` tests) while the paragraph is being set in a single line before being broken in to lines and those lines assigned to columns.

You could (for example) use `\pdfsavepos` to record a position and look in the next run at the x coordinate of that position.